# Can't pre FindOneAndUpdate and change fields from the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a Blog using Mongoose and node.js
But I can't solve an issue that I am having: Basically I am trying to get on pre FindOneAndUpdate hook the new post that I am pushing to the data blog,take the content from it,render using(markdown it) and save on contentHTML the html content rendered.

```
    const BlogSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  id: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
    require: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  premium: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    require: true,
  },
  settings: [
    {
      permissions: [
        {
          roleID: {
            type: Number,
            require: true,
            default: "everyone",
          },
        },
      ],
      channelID: {
        type: Number,
        require: true,
      },
      ownerID: {
        type: Number,
        require: true,
      },
      region: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  posts: [
    {
      tags: [
        {
          type: String,
          require: false,
          lowercase: true,
        },
      ],
      author: [
        {
          id: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
          },
          name: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
          },
          icon: {
            type: String,
            require: true,
          },
        },
      ],
      upVotes: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        require: true,
        lowercase: true,
        default: 0,
      },
      downVotes: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true,
        require: true,
        lowercase: true,
        default: 0,
      },
      id: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        unique: true,
        default: shortid.generate,
      },
      title: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
      },
      content: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
      },
      contentHTML: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        default: "",
      },
      date: {
        type: String,
        default: moment().format("MMM Do YY"),
        require: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date(),
    require: true,
  },
});
BlogSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function (next) {
  var index = Object.keys(this.getUpdate().$push.posts);
  var post = this.getUpdate().$push.posts[index];
  var content = post.content;
  var title = post.title;
  this.findOne({ name: this.getQuery().name }).then(async (result) => {
    result.posts.find((post) => post.title === title).contentHTML =
      md.render(content);

    result.save();
  });

  next();
});
```

Sometimes, don't know why the code is working,but once I create a new post with different name,the code crashes and I get this [image]

the problem is that when I console.log the title that I am trying to get, it's working, I get the title from the new post and the content too,but I don't know why I can't find this a post that contains those args. Could someone Help me please?

And this is the code that I am using to push the new post to the data

```
  app.post("/create/:name/post", (req, res, next) => {
    for (let i in req.body) {
      if (req.body[i].length <= 0) return res.send(`Invalid ${[i]} provided`);
    }
    Blog.findOneAndUpdate(
      { name: req.params.name },
      { $push: { posts: [req.body] } },
      (err, result) => {
        if (result === null) return res.send(`Could not find this blog!`);
        else {
          res.json({
            icon: "success",
            msg: `Post ${req.body.title} created`,
          });
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at the line 'result.posts.find((post) => post.title === title).contentHTML =' and verify that it indeed finds a post each time?

Comment: @sreisman it says that /home/bruno/projects/dcblog/src/models/blog.js:132
        (post) => post.title === this.getUpdate()["$push"].posts[0].title
                                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined